# How to sum any credits before debits SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to sum the all credits that occur before a debit, then sum all the debits after credit within a 4 day time period.

**Table**

```
ACCT |Date      | Amount  | Credit or debit
-----+----------+---------+----------------
 152 |8/14/2017 |   48    |   C
 152 |8/12/2017 |   22.5  |   D
 152 |8/12/2017 |   40    |   D
 152 |8/11/2017 |  226.03 |   C
 152 |8/10/2017 |  143    |   D
 152 |8/10/2017 |  107.23 |   C
 152 |8/10/2017 |   20    |   D
 152 |8/10/2017 |   49.41 |   C
```

My query should only sum if there is credit before the debit. the results will have 3 rows with the data above.

Output needed:

```
acct            DateRange                   credit_amount    debit_amount  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
152            2017-10-14 to 2017-10-18       49.41            20
152            2017-10-14 to 2017-10-18      107.23            143
152            2017-10-14 to 2017-10-18      226.03            62.5
```

The last one is summing the two debits until there is a credit.

1. First find the first credit.
2. sum the credits if there are more then 1 before a debit.
3. then find the debit and sum together until the next credit.

I only need the case where the credit date is before the debit date.  The 48 on 8/14 is ignored because there is no debit after it.

The logic is to see if the account was credited then debited after it.

**My attempt**

```
    DECLARE @StartDate DATE
    DECLARE @EndDate DATE
    DECLARE @OverallEndDate DATE

    SET @OverallEndDate = '2017-08-14'
    SET @StartDate = '2017-08-10'
    SET @EndDate = dateadd(dd, 4, @startDate);

    WITH Dates
    AS (
     SELECT @StartDate AS sd, @EndDate AS ed, @OverallEndDate AS od
     UNION ALL
     SELECT dateadd(dd, 1, sd), DATEADD(dd, 1, ed), od
     FROM Dates
     WHERE od > sd
     ), credits
    AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT A.Acct, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @StartDate, 120), 10) + 'to' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @EndDate, 120), 10) AS DateRange, credit_amount, debit_amount
     FROM (
       SELECT t1.acct, sum(amount) AS credit_amount, MAX(t1.datestart) AS c_datestart
       FROM [Transactions] T1
       WHERE Credit_or_debit = 'C' AND T1.Datestart BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND T1.[acct] = '152' AND T1.Datestart <= (
           SELECT MIN(D1.Datestart)
           FROM [Transactions] D1
           WHERE T1.acct = D1.acct AND D1.Credit_or_debit = 'D' AND D1.Datestart BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
           )
       GROUP BY T1.acct
       ) AS A
     CROSS JOIN (
       SELECT t2.acct, sum(amount) AS debit_amount, MAX(t2.datestart) AS c_datestart
       FROM [Transactions] T2 AND T2.DBCR = 'D' AND T2.Datestart BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND T2.[acct] = '152' AND T2.Datestart <= (
           SELECT MAX(D1.Datestart)
           FROM [Transactions] D1
           WHERE T2.acct = D1.acct AND D1.Credit_or_debit = 'D' AND D1.Datestart BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
           )
       GROUP BY T2.acct
       ) AS B
     WHERE A.acct = B.acct AND A.c_datestart <= B.d_datestart
     )
    SELECT *
    FROM credits
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Update:

The date stored is actually date timestamped. That is how I verify whether the debit is > credit.

Comment: Also assume that you need to handle the case of two or more credits before the next debit. What happens in this case?

Comment: So, your first step should be describing your logical flow, which looks something like this: (1) Find first credit -- (2) Find next credit -- (3) Sum all debits between these two credits [Easiest if you have an ID or other unique field per row]  (4) If debits found, output row. (5) If debits found, loop to 2  (6) End process.  Expanding what happens if there are no debits between two credits should also be added to this flow. Then you are ready for the next step.

Comment: What determines the order in your data? I can't see a way to keep that order by using an `ORDER BY`,  which is a problem based on your described goal.

Comment: Your output does not match your data. You have dates in the output that don't exist in the sample data. And your date string are inconsistent. You have MDY and YMD. And it seems your output is dependent on some sort of order but there is nothing in your data to provide order.

Comment: Do you have columns as the Id - Primary key? Or do you have time with date?

Comment: You can't do this based on the columns you've shown, because there is no column that can be used as an ORDER BY to reliably return the data. If that's your entire table design, then it's flawed. If it's not, then include more data that will allow the proper sorting of the data to allow such a calculation, and we might be able  to help.

Comment: The problem that everyone has is: How can we determine whether the transactions are "after" or "before" each other when they're from the same date? In your example, there are 4 records with a date of 8/10/2017, but how are they ordered?

Answer (score -1):

It should be clear now that you definitely need a column that specifies the sequential order of transactions, because otherwise you can't decide whether a debit is placed befor or after a credit when they both have the same `datestart`. Assuming that you have such a column (in my query I named it `ID`), a solution could be as follows, without recursion and also without a self-join. The problem can be solved using some of the *window functions* available since SQL Server 2008.

My solution processes the data in several steps that I implemented as a sequence of 2 CTEs and a final `PIVOT` query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20170810';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = dateadd(dd, 4, @StartDate);
DECLARE @DateRange nvarchar(24);

SET @DateRange = 
  CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @StartDate, 120) + ' to '
  + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @EndDate, 120);

WITH 
  blocks (acct, CD, amount, blockno, r_blockno) AS (
    SELECT acct, Credit_or_debit, amount
    ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acct ORDER BY ID ASC)
     - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acct, Credit_or_debit ORDER BY ID ASC)
    ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acct ORDER BY ID DESC)
     - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acct, Credit_or_debit ORDER BY ID DESC)
    FROM Transactions
    WHERE datestart BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
      AND Credit_or_debit IN ('C','D') -- not needed, if always true
  ),
  blockpairs (acct, CD, amount, pairno) AS (
    SELECT acct, CD, amount
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY acct, CD ORDER BY blockno)
    FROM blocks
    WHERE (blockno > 0 OR CD = 'C') -- remove leading debits
      AND (r_blockno > 0 OR CD = 'D') -- remove trailing credits
  )
SELECT acct, @DateRange AS DateRange
, amt.C AS credit_amount, amt.D AS debit_amount
FROM blockpairs PIVOT (SUM(amount) FOR CD IN (C, D)) amt
ORDER BY acct, pairno;
```

And this is how it works:

**blocks**

Here, the relevant data is retrieved from the table, meaning that the date range filter is applied, and another filter on the `Credit_or_debit` column makes sure that only the values C and D are contained in the result (if this is the case by design in your table, then that part of the `WHERE` clause can be omitted). The essential part in this CTE is the difference of two rownumbers (`blockno`). Credits and debits are numbered separately, and their respective rownumber is subtracted from the overall row number. Within a consecutive block of debits or credits, these numbers will be the same for each record, and they will be different (higher) in later blocks of the same type. The main use if this numbering is to identify the very first block (number `0`) in order to be able to exclude it from
further processing in the next step in case it's a debit block. To be able to also identify the very last block (and filter it away in the next step if it's a credit block), a similar block numbering is made in the reverse order (`r_blockno`). The result (which I orderd just for visualization with your sample data) will look like this:

[image: Result of the blocks CTE]

**blockpairs**

In this CTE, as described before, the very first block is filtered away if it's a debit block, and the very last block is filtered away if it's a credit block. Doing this, the number of remaining blocks must be even, and the logical order of blocks must be a sequence of pairs of credit and debit blocks, each pair starting with a credit block and followed by its associated debit block. Each pair of credit/debit blocks will result in a single row in the end. To associate the credit and debit blocks correctly in the query, I give them the same number by using separate numberings per type (the *n*-th credit block and the *n*-th debit block are associated by giving them the same number *n*). For this numbering, I use the `DENSE_RANK` function, for all records in a block to obtain the same number (`pairno`) and make the numbering gapless. For numbrting the blocks of the same type, I reuse the the `blockno` field described above for ordering. The result in your example (again sorted for visualization):

[image: Result of the blockpairs CTE]

**The final PIVOT query**

Finally, the `credit_amount` and `debit_amount` are aggregated over the respective blocks grouping by `acct` and `pairno` and then diplayed side-by-side using a `PIVOT` query.

[image: Final result]

Although the column `pairno` isn't visible, it is used for sorting the resulting records.